# Oracle Service Bus Java

Tags: oracle, service, ejb, bus

I have an EJB which has as input argument and return value a JAXB mapped complex structure (with subclasses etc).

Now I want to deploy this on the Oracle Service Bus 11g.  I can create a business proxy invoking the EJB, but only with basic types (int, ...).

How do i tunnel the XML between EJB and OSB?  Any advanced OSB information is appreciated, as I don't know much about it.

Comment: does it support XMLObject data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, it turns out the OSB supports (afaik only) Apache XMLBeans.   Thus if you declare parameters and return values of type org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject it works.  I did get some errors concerning DOM v3 not being implemented and some crashes in the oracle DOM implementation, so I just use the XmlObject to create an XML string, and the reparse it.

@Euclides:  I have XMLObject and XmlObject in my classpath.   I need the second (lower case).  Thanks for the hint, anyway.